# restrict data rows in datalist and add a load more button in the footer

Tags: asp.net, ajax, datalist

datalist is as follows:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataListComments" runat="server" 
                                        DataKeyField="Pk_Comment_Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceComments" Width="100%">
                                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Gray" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                        <HeaderTemplate>
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" BackColor="Gray" 
                                                ForeColor="White" Text="Comments" Width="100%" />
                                        </HeaderTemplate>
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <div class="CommentBox">
                                                <div class="CommentImage">
                                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"
                                                        NavigateUrl='<%# "Profile.aspx?uid=" + Eval("fk_User_Id")%>'>
                                                        <asp:Image ID="imgUserC" runat="server"
                                                            ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Profile_Pic") %>' CssClass="scaling-image" />
                                                    </asp:HyperLink>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="CommentInfo">
                                                    <div class="CommentUsername">
                                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="linkUserProfile" runat="server"
                                                            NavigateUrl='<%# "Profile.aspx?uid=" + Eval("fk_User_Id")%>'><%# Eval("Username") %></asp:HyperLink>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="CommentDate">(<%# Eval("Date") %>)</div>
                                                    <div class="CommentDescription"><%# Eval("Description") %></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:DataList>
```

Now, suppose there are 24 entries for [comments] in the database... I want to show only 3 here... And add a load more button in the footer template, on clicking this load more 5 more comments should be displayed..

If there is a possible solution to this with ajax, i wouldn't have any problem with that. I just need a working solution to this, as I am clueless on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite complicated when you are using runat server controls like gridview and datalist etc.

To achieve your goal:

1. You need to create web service
2. Get records from data base by using the service and JavaScript
3. Append the result at bottom by using JavaScript

These are things you need to do, and many other problem will start when you will work with server controls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Can you please suggest how do I call items from database in following format: Initially : Just 3 rows, on load more click skip those 3 and take next 3... Then again on click skip 6 and take next 3.. This goes until all rows are appended, and then hide the load more button. I guess this can be achieved using skip() and take(). But I'm using linq and I'm not sure how would I do this. I'm basically designing a comment box, and I don't want to show all the comments at once.. (Same function as in FB u can say).. Any suggestions or ideas about best way of doing it?